# Replace a file in svn HEAD

Tags: svn, version-control

Unfortunately, I cannot explain exactly what happened. The result is the following: In my repository I have a file `foo.bar` for which the correct version is `HEAD-1`. How can I create a new revision, such that the only difference between `HEAD` and `HEAD+1` is that `foo.bar` in `HEAD+1` is the one from `HEAD-1`. All other elements of the repository should be identical in `HEAD+1` to those of `HEAD`.

By invoking

```
svn update -rHEAD-1 foo.bar
```

I obtain a working copy which is the one I want to become `HEAD+1`. However, `svn status` doesn't show anything.

I hope my question make some sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, although the rest of the changes in your HEAD revision are fine, you did a mistake in foo.bar and you want to retrieve that for your next revision. Here's how:

Take a snapshot of your `foo.bar` from the previous revision, using the command you have specified

```
svn update -r HEAD-1 foo.bar
```

Then, make a copy of this file and save it as `foo.correct.bar`

```
cp foo.bar foo.correct.bar
```

Restore the file to your current revision

```
svn update -r HEAD foo.bar
```

Then, copy over your saved (and correct version of) `foo.bar` to overwrite the current messed-up version

```
mv foo.correct.bar foo.bar
```

Commit it back in as revision HEAD+1

```
svn commit foo.bar -m "Restoring foo.bar from older revision HEAD-1"
```

Hope that helps,
Sudipta

Comment: I guess this is a classical example of KISS (=Keep It Stupid Simple). I thought I should use some fancy-svn-trick... Thanks a lot!